# NameError: name 'models' is not defined

Tags: django, python-2.7, cmd

I have a problem, disturbing. my models is to at the bottom. 
so any orders I give, the only error is that 'Name Error: name 'models' is not defined' each time I put it in my cmd. am kindly asking anyone to help me here... thank you

Comment: Will need to see some code to debug!

Comment: You need to post your code but you either did not import Django models, or you are spelling something wrong somewhere.

Comment: *looks into crystal ball* I'm seeing line 143 in your code. Good luck that's the best I can do.

Comment: Specifically, we need to know how/where in your project you are importing Django models to even begin to help you.

Comment: Hello everyone, the models.py is here:'from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Bookmark(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(maxlength=200)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    link=models.ForeignKey(Link)'